# The program has exited with code -536870873 (0xe0000027)

Tags: c#

While running the code the program is automatically exiting from the debug process.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher wmiData = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\SecurityCenter2", "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct");
        ManagementObjectCollection data = wmiData.Get();

        try
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject virusChecker in data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(virusChecker["displayName"]);
                Console.WriteLine(virusChecker["instanceGuid"]);
                Console.WriteLine(virusChecker["pathToSignedProductExe"]);
                Console.WriteLine(virusChecker["productState"]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
        }
```

Comment: Post the full exception text

Comment: Have you put breakpoints inside of your `try` block to see where the exception is being thrown?

Comment: Tried and works. 0xe0000027 is the "ERROR_ALREADY_RUNNING" hresult. In what context are you executing that code?

Comment: I am getting error in "ManagementObjectCollection data = wmiData.Get();" line of code.

Comment: The program '[3400] CheckWindowsDetails.exe' has exited with code -536870873 (0xe0000027).

Comment: @Ralf I am executing the code for windows defender update.